# Gravity sensor & work with value change

Tags: java, android

this is part of my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener,
                               View.OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    SensorManager sm;
    TextView gravitySensor;
    Sensor gravSensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gravSensor=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
        gravitySensor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gravity);
        sm.registerListener(this, gravSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        gravitySensor.setText("X: "+sensorEvent.values[0]+
                "\nY: "+sensorEvent.values[1]+
                "\nZ: "+sensorEvent.values[2]);
    }
```

The output from sensors is transformed into text and showed in application as X, Y, Z value. 
I want to work with Z value - so when the Z is lower than 9.5 text (e.g. via `Toast` text) appears and informs user, that the Z value was changed.
Is it possible to make this easy way? Thanks for help!

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: Beware: Except when the device lays absolutely still, the Z value will change all the time. Depending on what you're actually up to, you should probably use some sort of averaging or filtering, otherwise you'll end up showing the Toast all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you do it here:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    gravitySensor.setText("X: "+sensorEvent.values[0]+
            "\nY: "+sensorEvent.values[1]+
            "\nZ: "+sensorEvent.values[2]);

    if(sensorEvent.values[2] > 9.5) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Z value changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I don't see any problem.

---

To avoid multi-triggering:

```
boolean isChanged = false;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    gravitySensor.setText("X: "+sensorEvent.values[0]+
            "\nY: "+sensorEvent.values[1]+
            "\nZ: "+sensorEvent.values[2]);

    if(sensorEvent.values[2] > 9.5 && !isChanged) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Z value changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       isChanged = true;
    } else /* if (something more clever)*/ {
       isChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for difficulties and I did not imagine that the solution is so easy :/

Comment: I can see possible problem - when the value is > 9,5 the Toast text appears, but never disappears

Comment: This is happening because the sensor triggers it all the time, you have to implement a "smart" on-off mechanism. I edit the post just for a basic idea...